# Avoid exposing the backend details to client in spring-boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, security, spring-security

When hitting a wrong/non-existing **spring-boot** endpoint. Code level class details are exposed. This could be marked as a security concern.

**Example**

**Request**

```
localhost:8500/api/1.0/service/../msc -> this is a bad formatted endpoint, which does not exist.
```

**Response**

```
{
    "timestamp": "2024-01-31T08:33:44.321+0000",
    "status": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "message": "Failed to find lookupPath '/api/1.0/msc' within requestUri '/api/1.0/service/../msc'. This could be because the path has invalid encoded characters or isn't normalized.; nested exception is org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceUrlEncodingFilter$LookupPathIndexException: Failed to find lookupPath '/api/1.0/msc' within requestUri '/api/1.0/service/../msc'. This could be because the path has invalid encoded characters or isn't normalized.",
    "path": "/api/1.0/service/../msc"
}
```

Just by looking on the error message we can understand that there's a spring-boot app running behind the scene, as code level details are exposed in the message, it could be a vulnerability.

How can we send a generic messages instead of entire exception details to client?

Also I have tried to user @ControllerAdvice, but exceptions are not caught inside it. It seems this has raised before even reaching to the controller itself.

```
@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
public ResponseEntity handleException(Exception ex) {
log.error("Exception in flow", ex);
ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body("Internal Server Error");
}
```

Comment: there are several ways of customizing the error handing you can read about it here https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/3.2.2/reference/htmlsingle/#web.servlet.spring-mvc.error-handling and here are all the flags you can set in properties to customize it https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/3.2.2/reference/htmlsingle/#appendix.application-properties.server

Answer (score 1):

You could use a combination of things to handle that exception and to not leak it, see https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc#recent-updates to check different type of hanlders.

Answer (score 0):

You can ask the server to never provide the automatic message details by adding the property

```
server.error.include-message: never
```

For more details check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71499558/7237884) for another similar issue.

Comment: Right, this property is not supported in spring-boot. 2.2.4, So in that case I think I have to upgrade only to newer version, and Exception Handler with Exception is also not able to caught this. @Panan

Answer (score -1):

Did you try using ExceptionHandler on the controller level advice.
Then handle the specific business exceptions.
On the handler you can add custom business messages, also you can try to retain some of the details from the original exception.
You can have a specific handler for Exception as well which can act as a catch all case. Something like below,

```
@Configuration
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {
@ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
public ResponseEntity<Response>
handleMethodArgumentException(MethodArgumentNotValidException 
methodArgumentNotValidException)
```

Comment: For that to work, we need to know the exception before hand right, can we not handle this for all client side exception once.

Comment: yes you can by defining `@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)` which will catch alla exceptions.

Comment: That will catch all the exceptions, even the server side as well, how will we differentiate ? For server side exception we want to send the internal server error, with no details of what happened wrong. For client side, we want the client to know that something is wrong with the body. @Toerktumlare

Comment: you are giving us an impossible equation, you don't want to differentiate between exceptions, but then you want to differentiate. Also i dont understand what you mean when you say ClientSideExcecption and ServerSideException. All of this is code on the server. You are being very unclear now. If you want us to help you, you need to provide all of your requirments upfront, in detail so that we dont come with suggestions and you introduce new requirements as we go. Your question was `How can we send a generic messages instead of entire exception details to client?` and here is the answer.

Comment: @Toerktumlare I have added few details in the question.